# Excel sheet to SQL table upload automation

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, office365

I am trying to find the easiest and simplest and quickest way to upload a sheet from Excel to a table in SQL Server 2012 automatically every morning as a job from a location on my folder to the table.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you have any part of the process working?

Comment: i have manually added it so far. just looking online i read ssis is the best solution but i dont have visual studios

Comment: SSIS runs on the SQL server. Do you have access to the SQL server? Have you tried to run this from SQL or just from Windows. You can schedule tasks in the server with the agent.

Comment: i have access to sql server  and the the server and the table i am trying to dump this into.  the schedule tasks does not work for excel sheets from what i read online?

Comment: There are several examples via Google. See this one [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017) for example.

Comment: thanks but looking at this, it just shows how you can upload from excel to a table in sql server using ssis but does not state anything about automating the task? i can go about looking into it using this method but just want to make sure if automation is possible.

Comment: You need to use the SQL server agent for that. It can schedule tasks for you.

Answer (score 1):

SSIS is the ETL tool you could use, but if it’s a very simple job you can just write a BCP command.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017

The way the schedule it is to add the task to the agent job on the server. A few things to bear in mind with ETL:

Will your file be named the same each day?

Do you need to retain archived versions of the file?

How do you do error handling if it’s absent or malformed?

Does the DDL need to change periodically to accomodate new date ranges (I.e. new day/month year)
Will this pattern be reused in the future?

Do you need to test logically (duplicates/logical fallacies/referential integrity etc)?

Under whose account will the job run (hint, don’t use your own - get a service account)?

The more complex the answers are to these types of questions the more likely you’ll need a real ETL tool like SSIS

Comment: thanks! i found this guide online for ssis. 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/ssis/moving-data-from-excel-to-sql-server-10-steps-to-follow/

do you think this is sufficient for this job? also how will ssis  handle name changes to the file and column name changes if they were to happen?

Comment: File names are usually done by patterns and wildcards. E.g. you might have a file called sales_20191123 which, tomorrow, will be called sales_20191124. Here you’d set up a mask - the directory and the first part of the path are static, the rest are wildcards

Comment: Column changes are more tricky, you can do it by column index position but personally I’d avoid that, if your input is that unstable I’d focus my dev efforts on hardening it up. But that’s situation dependent of course.

Comment: Finally, I wouldn’t bother with red gate initially - vanilla SSIS is almost certainly fine. That said the red gate tutorial looks fine.